# How to get video frame buffer from gstreamer to my C application

Tags: c, video, gstreamer

I am using gstreamer framework for recording a video. In that filesink element is being used for storing a video data into file. But i want to store video data into my custom file from my application. Is there any way to get video frame buffer to my application? Please find my current application sample code.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
  {
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *encoder, *queue, *sink, *mytextoverlay;
GstCaps *caps;
GstBus *bus;
GstMessage *msg;
GMainLoop *loop;

/* Initialize GStreamer */
gst_init(&argc, &argv);
loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

/* Create the elements */
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");
source = gst_element_factory_make("qtiqmmfsrc", "camsrc");
encoder = gst_element_factory_make("qtic2venc", "encoder");
mytextoverlay = gst_element_factory_make ("textoverlay", "mytextoverlay");
queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue");
sink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "filesink");

if (!pipeline || !source || !encoder || !queue || !sink) {
    g_print("One or more elements could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
}

g_object_set (G_OBJECT(mytextoverlay), "text", "hello world", NULL);

/* Set the properties */
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "camera", 0, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "location", "/data/test.h265", NULL);

/* Set the caps on the source */
caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
                           "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "NV12",
                           "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
                           "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
                           "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                           NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "caps", caps, NULL);
gst_caps_unref(caps);

/* Build the pipeline */
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, mytextoverlay,encoder, queue, sink, NULL);
if (!gst_element_link_many(source, mytextoverlay, encoder, queue, sink, NULL)) {
    g_print("Failed to link elements. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
}

/* Start playing the pipeline */
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

/* Wait until error or EOS */
bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
                                 GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

/* Parse message */
if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
            gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
            g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
                       GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), err->message);
            g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n",
                       debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
            g_clear_error(&err);
            g_free(debug_info);
            break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            g_print("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
            break;
        default:
            /* Unexpected message received. Ignore it. */
            break;
    }
    gst_message_unref(msg);
}

/* Free resources */
gst_object_unref(bus);
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref(pipeline);
g_main_loop_unref(loop);

return 0;
```

}